# Python paramiko error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" only for a particular computer

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

While trying to connect to a remote Unix server using `paramiko` I am getting the error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Surprisingly, when I try to run the same script, from a different laptop with same server, username and password, I am able to connect to the server and execute remote commands.

```
 >>> import paramiko
 >>> ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
 >>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 >>> ssh.connect(ftpipaddress,username ='akar',password ='change')
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Absolutely no clue what might be the issue with the laptop having same Python 2.7 and `paramiko` package installed in it. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/client.html), `connect` method does not return anything. In terms of Python, it means, that this method returns `None`. You are probably looking for `exec_command` method:

> ```
> exec_command(command, bufsize=-1, timeout=None, get_pty=False)
> ```
>
> Execute a command on the SSH server. A new Channel is opened and the
>   requested command is executed. The command’s input and output streams
>   are returned as Python file-like objects representing stdin, stdout,
>   and stderr.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - command (str) – the command to execute
> - bufsize (int) – interpreted the same way as by the built-in file() function in Python
> - timeout (int) – set command’s channel timeout. See Channel.settimeout.settimeout
>
> **Returns:**   the stdin, stdout, and stderr of the executing command, as a 3-tuple
>
> **Raises SSHException:**   if the server fails to execute the command

Comment: I have edited the question...the issue still arises when I am NOT giving stdin, stdout, stderr

Comment: Hmm... Could you, please, move the code into a file and run it under Python? Will it produce the full traceback?

Answer (score 2):

please see this comment.
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1078#issuecomment-596771584

> RafaARV commented on Mar 9
> @BertCatsburg I was getting exactly the same error. For me it was a
> garbage collector error so, in order to work around this I did my own
> deletion:

```
if client is not None:
    client.close()
    del client, stdin, stdout, stderr
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, though my error reads "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" whereas yours says "... is not iterable".

Combining answers from [@Sameer Naik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65416152/15746989) and [@Minho-cyber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63948793/15746989) - Adding these lines at the end of my script worked for me:

```
del stdin, stdout, stderr
ssh.close()
sys.exit()
```

Of course, you'll also need to "import sys" if you haven't already.

I also notice that though it wasn't exiting gracefully, my script did seem to be running as intended even when it had that ugly error present. My script ran "touch test.txt" on the remote system and I then verified that it had appeared via a separate ssh session.

Answer (score 1):

use close&exit,you know
sys.exit()
ssh.close()
After hunting solutions on Web, I add above sentences . Problem vanished. Python ocde passed.

```
    finally:
        print('end')
        sys.exit()
        ssh.close()
```